# How to stop seeing 'answer=' after I run a function y=f(x)

Tags: matlab, command-line

Sometimes, I write a matlab program, say y=f(x), and then put semicolon everywhere necessary to purposefully stop seeing any output at all. However, even though, an output 'ans=...' appears in my command window. This ... is the final value of y at the end of a loop etc.

Why is it happening and how can I stop seeing that? I put semicolon everywhere?

P.S. suppose I want to display a particular value of a variable v, then also this 'ans=...' occurs at the end of showing the value(s) of v. How can I stop this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you putting a semicolon after the function call? `y=f(x);`

Comment: Luis: I didn't first; now I did in the command window, and the 'ans=...' doesn't pop up anymore :) Thanks!

Comment: As I see in the comments of @michael_0815 the problem could not be totally solved. If you post some of the code, we could do further analysis concerning this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To suppress the output of the function end result, you need to also put a semicolon in the caller, not only in the function itself

```
y=f(x);
```

To display a variable value without the 'ans=' use something like

```
disp(['v = ' num2str(v)])
```

or simply

```
disp(v)
```

Comment: I won't!But the problem recurred even after I did both: putting semicolon after the function[y]=f(x); and also doing the same when I called it in the command prompt. So it did work but not always. But that might be matlab's internal problems: it did happen before that I was getting different outputs in the command prompt, even WITHOUT changing anything a bit!